# Python - palindrome numbers

Tags: python, recursion, palindrome

I am trying to write a program that finds the smallest pallindrome cube. My code:

```
def cubepal():
    i=3
    if str(i**3)==str(i**3)[::-1]:
        return i**3
    else:
        i=i+1
        cubepal()
```

I am pretty sure that the first part is correct, but the last three lines make the program run in an endless loop. In the end it only says the problem is on line

```
if str(i**3)==str(i**3)[::-1]:
```

I don't see why there is a problem. Could somebody help?

Comment: Looks to me the smallest palindrome cube is `0` because `0^3=0` and `0` is a palindrome.

Comment: Please indent your function code properly

Comment: @CommuSoft : Yes, this is why i inserted i=3. I am searching for a 3-digit number.

Comment: @L.R.: `3^3=27`, this isn't a three digit number either.

Comment: @xnx: Sorry, what does that mean? (sorry, very bad with computer terms...)

Comment: Ok, sure, a two digit number would do, it's just that such a palindrome doesn't exist.

Comment: @L.R.: It means that you use spaces so that it is clear what code is underneath what method. This is even forced in Python. Done this now.

Comment: @L.R. it means that the code you post in your question should be indented as it is in your working code: ie 4 spaces for the function block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you don't scope your variables correctly.

You call `cubepal` and `cubepal` initializes `i=3` now when you perform the recursive call, `i` is a local variable equal to `3`.

```
def cubepal(i):
    if str(i**3)==str(i**3)[::-1]:
        return i**3
    else:
        return cubepal(i+1)
```

and call it with `cubepal(3)`.

Although for such cases, one better not uses recursion: if it is expected that `i` will be very large (this is not the case here), but it could be, for a memory-inefficient Python interpeter, result in a call-stack that scales with the value of the result.

A better way to handle this is I guess a `while` loop.

```
def cubepal():
    i = 3
    while str(i**3) != str(i**3)[::-1]:
        i = i+1
    return i**3
```

This will in general be more efficient as well, because calling a function leads to some overhead regarding bookkeeping and the call-stack.

Comment: I think you need to `return cubepal(i+1)`

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to do this:

```
def cubepal(i):
    if str(i**3)==str(i**3)[::-1]:
        return i**3
    else:
        return cubepal(i+1)

print(cubepal(3))
```

which yields "343".

Of course, there is no point to do it this way in Python since Python lacks TCO.